# Build Pipeline - package getting uploaded into wrong path - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, cicd

i'm new to azure devops, my CI(Build) pipeline works properly and package is getting generated as well, once i run the CD(Release) pipeline the package is getting deployed in the azure web app as well, but it is getting uploaded on the in the different path (/data/SitePackages) not in the home directory (/site/wwwroot) is there anything missing in the pipeline?

[image: this is how build pipeline looks like]

Answer (score 0):

Base on the statement on the documentation "[**Run your app from a ZIP package - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package)", if set '**`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`**' to be '**`1`**' on Azure Web App to enable running from a package, the deployment will not extract the package content to the D:\home\site\wwwroot directory of your app. Instead, it uploads the ZIP file as-is to D:\home\data\SitePackages, and creates a packagename.txt in the same directory, that contains the name of the ZIP package to load at runtime.

[image]

For your case, it should because you have enabled running from package on your app setting.

Comment: @yudi, Any update from you? Have you checked with the suggestion mentioned in my above answer? Is it helpful for you?